# No visible @interface for 'NSManagedObjectContext' declares

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data

[image]

[self.managedObjectContext deletedObjects:lastPoint];
This line shows me an error

No visible @interface for 'NSManagedObjectContext' declares the selector 'deletedObjects'.

Here is my code
can any one solve this?

Appdelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;


@end
```

Appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    /* crete the fetch request first*/
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"Rectangle"];
    NSError *requestError = nil;
    /*And execute the fetch request on the context*/
    NSArray *rectangle = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&requestError];

    /*make sure we get the array*/

    if ([rectangle count] > 0) {
        /*delete the last person in the array*/
        Rectangle *lastPoint = [rectangle lastObject];
        [self.managedObjectContext deletedObjects:lastPoint];

        if ([lastPoint isDeleted]) {
            NSLog(@"Successfully deleted the last point...");

            NSError *savingError = nil;
            if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&savingError]) {
                NSLog(@"successfully saved the context");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Failed to save the context");
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to delete the last point");
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Could not find any rectangle entities in the context.");
    }
    return  YES;
}
```

Comment: were you able to solve the problem? @Bhargav?

Comment: yes I solve this problem by modifying line in Appdelegate.m
`[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:lastPoint];`

Comment: @Bhargav please explain in breaf. i am facing same error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33365748/ios-coredata-unique-constraint-failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

> No visible @interface for 'NSManagedObjectContext' declares the
>   selector 'deletedObjects'.

tells you that the class `NSManagedObjectContext` doesn't implement the method `deletedObjects`. You can check this in the [API documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/deleteObject:).

You can use `deleteObject:` to delete single objects. So change your code to:

`[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:lastPoint];`

Comment: can you show the declaration of your property `managedObjectContext`? maybe this is not in fact an object of type `NSManagedObjectContext` (although I wouldn't think this is likely)

Comment: `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;


@end`

Comment: sorry for alignment I can't do here

Comment: I added it in my question

Comment: hmm, it's usually better to **update the question** rather than posting code in the comments :) anyway, it looks like your property `managedObjectContext ` indeed is of type `NSManagedObjectContext `.

Comment: you will have to provide more information of the error, maybe even a screenshot with the error in the code. it seems strange that your compiler complains about calling `deleteObject:` on an `NSManagedObjectContext`

Comment: thanks for the screenshot. did you try changing: `[self.managedObjectContext deletedObject:lastPoint];` to `[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:lastPoint];` as I suggested in the answer? @Bhargav

Comment: are you sure? did you spell it correctly, please read carefully, you need to write **delete** instead of **deleted** --> `deleteObject`

Answer (score 0):

As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSManagedObjectContext/deletedObjects) says deletedObjects is the read only property, so it has only getter method without any parameters
So you should access it just by using next

```
self.managedObjectContext.deletedObjects
```